# when i am trying to update a attribute from csv file to 5820 products its gives me 500 error in magento

Tags: php, magento

when i am trying to update a attribute from CVS file of one category which contains 5820 products in magento whenever the loops runs its shows 500 error but when i tried the same thing in local where the product number was less 50-100 it executed without any problem?

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app ()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $data = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        if(!empty($data[0]))
        {
           $line_of_text[] = $data; 
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        } 

    }    
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}
// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'stocks.csv';
$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
foreach ($csv as $key => $value) 
{
     $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(12);
     $productslist = $products->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
     foreach($productslist as $_product) 
     {
         if($value[0]==$_product->getSku())
         {
             //echo $_product->getId();
             $_product->setTag($value[1]);
             $_product->save();
          }
      }
}
```